# Upload speed publish Service Fabric application from Azure VM to Azure cluster

Tags: azure-service-fabric

I am trying to publish my Service Fabric application from a Azure VM as was suggested here: [Operation timed out publishing Service Fabric application to Azure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38688268/operation-timed-out-publishing-service-fabric-application-to-azure)

The Azure VM is created in the same datacenter as my Service Fabric cluster. But for some reason I am only getting upload speeds from around 200 Kbps.

With the hard-coded 10 minutes timeout in the publish script in Visual Studio, this is not enough to get my application published.

Are there any suggestions on how I might increase my upload speed?

Comment: Is there anything special around how you configured the cluster? What size machines? Are the machines busy? Is the state of the cluster good? My experience of this shows that when I've made a major mistake and my cluster is stressed, writing to the image store is slow, but generally it works fine. Also - are you hitting any credit limits on azure?

Comment: Did you see this topic about differential packages: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34873891/differential-packaging/34886586   they are smaller than full packages, and therefore should deploy faster.

Comment: @NickRandell I upgraded the machine size and that did it. Thanks! If you can post it as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since version 2.5.216 of the Service Fabric SDK, you have to ability to compress the package prior to sending.

Add the following line to the PublishProfiles\Cloud.xml file to enable compression (and change the timeout from 10 minutes to 60 minutes if you want to):

```
<CopyPackageParameters CopyPackageTimeoutSec="3600" CompressPackage="true" />
```

See [this lengthy disucssion](https://github.com/Azure/service-fabric-issues/issues/10)